# Spring 3 Webflow with JSF 2 links with _eventId not transitioning

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-webflow

I have gotten h:commandButton and h:commandLink to work, but the simple h:outputLink will not. I am trying JSF 2 (with facelets) code below:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{flowExecutionUrl}&amp;_eventId=displayBrief&amp;briefId=#{brief.briefId}">
    <h:outputText value="#{brief.eventName}"/>                                      
</h:outputLink>
```

The correct link is created, but when clicked, the same page remains.

Comment: Can you also post the rendered html for the anchor tag using Firebug or some other tool.

Comment: That behavior sounds like there is no transition in that state for that event. Can you watch the HTTP request and see if what you expect is being sent?